# C#: Why does my GPA Calculator keep making exception-handling errors?

Tags: c#, exception

I am creating a GPA calculator. When there isn't any grades inside the text boxes, it always crashes. It fully works without the try/catch, but I am trying to have a messagebox pop up that says there has been an error, but it always keeps failing and going to the debugging error screen.

I have tried using the basic try and catch methods, but sadly, there was no avail. I have also tried defining the variables first then using the try catch methods. I had no errors but it keeps debugging/crashing when I enter wrong grade values. I would want it to send a messagebox that says there was an error.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string math = txtMath.Text;
        string literature = txtLiterature.Text;
        string physics = txtPhysics.Text;
        string usva = txtusva.Text;
        string computerscience = txtComputerScience.Text;
        string filmstudy = txtFilmStudy.Text;
        string business = txtBusiness.Text;

        math = math.ToUpper();
        literature = literature.ToUpper();
        physics = physics.ToUpper();
        usva = usva.ToUpper();
        computerscience = computerscience.ToUpper();
        filmstudy = filmstudy.ToUpper();
        business = business.ToUpper();

        float math1 = 0f;
        float literature1 = 0f;
        float physics1 = 0f;
        float usva1 = 0f;
        float computerscience1 = 0f;
        float filmstudy1 = 0f;
        float business1 = 0f;

        try
        {
            math1 = Single.Parse(gradetoGrade(math));
            literature1 = Single.Parse(gradetoGrade(literature));
            physics1 = Single.Parse(gradetoGrade(physics));
            usva1 = Single.Parse(gradetoGrade(usva));
            computerscience1 = Single.Parse(gradetoGrade(computerscience));
            filmstudy1 = Single.Parse(gradetoGrade(filmstudy));
            business1 = Single.Parse(gradetoGrade(business));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


        float result = ((math1 + literature1 + physics1 + usva1 + 
        computerscience1 + filmstudy1 + business1) / 7);
        string strresult;
        strresult = result.ToString();
```

'''
Here's the function gradetograde if anyone wants to look at it
'''

```
    public string gradetoGrade(string grade)
    {
        switch (grade)
        {
            case "A" :
                grade = "4.0";
                break;
            case "A-":
                grade = "3.7";
                break;
            case "B+":
                grade = "3.3";
                break;
            case "B":
                grade = "3.0";
                break;
            case "B-":
                grade = "2.7";
                break;
            case "C+":
                grade = "2.3";
                break;
            case "C":
                grade = "2.0";
                break;
            case "C-":
                grade = "1.7";
                break;
            case "D+":
                grade = "1.3";
                break;
            case "D":
                grade = "1.0";
                break;
            case "F":
                grade = "0.0";
                break;
            default:
                break; 

        }
        return grade; 
    }
```

I hope instead of my program just breaking down, it would have a message box pop up saying there was an error. The calculator works fine, but I would like to have it show there was an error on the program, not the debugger. Do note I have a separate function (gradetograde) that doesn't have anything to do with the error.

Comment: And the message is? Also what is the code for _gradetoGrade_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your code in a `try`/`catch`, but look at your code below it:

```
float result = ((math1 + literature1 + physics1...
```

But wait, what happens if the `try` fails? You're using variables that were never set!

Initialize your `math1`, `literature1`, etc so that they are always set to some default value (for example, 0)

Answer (score 0):

You have a compiler error, right? the code doesn't run at all, because it can't.
And the reason is that you are trying to use a **local** (stress there) variable which is not initialized and that is not allowed.
You can use properties before initialize them, but not local variables.
Just assign anything to your local variables (like -1, or whatever suits your logic) and you will be ready to run.
And if you want to know which one is missing you can just check if every value is greater than 0, for example